# Haskell type synonym union?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I want to do something like the following

```hs
data Fruits = Apple | Orange | ...
data Meat = Chicken | Beef | ...

type Eats = Fruits | Meat
```

I wish to construct type `Eats` such that it is a union of two types. The point is that I want to do this without adding another layer of constructors. Is this possible in Haskell at all?

Comment: Why not an other data struct `data Eats`

Comment: Haskell's sum types are _tagged union_. you would want a function which receives one of two types. but Haskell insists on knowing the types upfront. it wants to know the _type_ (not types) that a function handles.

Comment: @Jozott Because I don't want another layer of constructors.

Comment: OCaml offers a related feature called *polymorphic variants*. But polymorphic variants actually have quite different compilation needs than regular data constructors (which OCaml calls *variants*), and they can have substantial run-time costs. Haskell just doesn't support them at all.

Comment: TLDR: Use `Either`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data Fruit = Apple | Orange | ...
data Meat = Chicken | Beef | ...
```

You can’t construct an untagged union directly. However, you can construct something that is *equivalent* to a tagged union (sum type) but that doesn’t require tags, using functions instead.

A sum type like `Either a b` can be represented by its pattern-matching function like `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`; the expression `either f g e` is equivalent to the `case` expression `case e of { Left x -> f x; Right y -> g y }`.

So whenever you would use `data Food = Fruit | Meat | Vegetable | …`, you could instead use the function equivalent to matching on this type. That is, converting from this:

```
data Food
  = Fruit Fruit
  | Meat Meat
  | Vegetable Vegetable
  -- …

-- Energy density in kilojoules per gram
newtype EnergyDensity = ED Word

foodED :: Food -> EnergyDensity
foodED (Fruit f)     = fruitED f
foodED (Meat m)      = meatED m
foodED (Vegetable v) = vegetableED v
-- …
```

To this:

```
{-# Language RankNTypes #-}

-- A food-matching function.
type FoodF r
  = (Fruit -> r)
  -> (Meat -> r)
  -> (Vegetable -> r)
  -- …
  -> r

-- A polymorphic matching function.
newtype Food = Food { matchFood :: forall r. FoodF r }

foodED :: Food -> EnergyDensity
foodED food = matchFood food
  (\ f -> fruitED f)
  (\ m -> meatED m)
  (\ v -> vegetableED v)
  -- …

-- Or, simplified:
--
-- f food = matchFood food fruitED meatED vegetableED
```

To construct this type, you simply make a `Food` which calls the appropriate case:

```
{-# Language BlockArguments #-}

fruit :: Fruit -> Food
fruit x = Food \ f _m _v -> f x

meat :: Meat -> Food
meat x = Food \ _f m _v -> m x

vegetable :: Vegetable -> Food
vegetable x = Food \ _f _m v -> v x
```

Since “positional” matching like this can be unwieldy, you could also introduce a record type for matching. However, this likely isn’t as “clean” or straightforward as you had in mind.

The basic problem is that we’re making a hierarchy of types and then trying to remove the resulting nested tags. It’s often preferable to avoid the nesting to begin with by making a single type of “foods”, where things like “is fruit” are properties of the food. This can be done dynamically, by defining functions:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

data Food
  = Apple
  | Orange
  -- …
  | Chicken
  | Beef
  -- …

isFruit :: Food -> Bool
isFruit Apple   = True
isFruit Orange  = True
-- …
isFruit Chicken = False
isFruit Beef    = False
-- …

data Animal = Fowl | Beast | Fish

foodAnimal :: Food -> Maybe Animal
foodAnimal Chicken = Just Fowl
foodAnimal Beef    = Just Beast
foodAnimal _       = Nothing

animalProducts :: [Food] -> Set Animal
animalProducts foods
  = Set.fromList
    [ animal
    | food <- foods
    , Just animal <- foodAnimal food
    ]
```

Or statically, if all of the categories are disjoint, using a type tag on the data type:

```
{-# Language
    DataKinds,
    GADTs,
    KindSignatures #-}

data Food (t :: FoodGroup) where
  Apple   :: Food 'FruitGroup
  Orange  :: Food 'FruitGroup
  -- …
  Chicken :: Food 'MeatGroup
  Beef    :: Food 'MeatGroup
  -- …

data FoodGroup
  = FruitGroup
  | MeatGroup
  | VegetableGroup
  -- …

-- Aliases for subsets of ‘Food’.
type Fruit     = Food 'FruitGroup
type Meat      = Food 'MeatGroup
type Vegetable = Food 'VegetableGroup

-- Non-meat cases are impossible because t=MeatGroup, so
-- we don’t need to match them, and don’t need to return
-- a ‘Maybe’-wrapped result.
meatAnimal :: Food 'MeatGroup -> Animal
meatAnimal Chicken = Fowl
meatAnimal Beef    = Beast
```

This can give you more type safety and convenience of pattern matching, but it also requires you to be careful about the design of your categories: where will you put `Tomato`?

Comment: I wonder if you could fake up something horrible with pattern synonyms and some `Typeable` mess to let you identify polymorphic variants across datatypes. Then some horrible business with type-level set unions and so on?

Answer (score 2):

From [the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type) you can read this

> `type` introduces a synonym for a type and uses the same data constructors.

If it introduces a *synonym*, then how can one word (`Eats`) be synonym of both other two words (`Fruits` and `Meat`) without causing ambiguity?

Considered that `Fruits` and `Meat` are ***types***, so they are expected where types are used, for instance in signatures. Now how would the compiler go about the following?

```hs
myfun :: Eats -> Int
-- some definition of myfun
```

Comment: easy: `myfun Apple = ...; myfun Beef = ...`.

Comment: @WillNess, but those would be of different type... Oh, maybe you mean that the OP could expect something like that to be plausible.

Comment: right. you said "how would you define such a thing" to which I responded. writing such definition is easy. giving it a type, not so much. :)