# Haskell equivalent of multiple inheritence for ADT constructors?

Tags: kotlin, haskell

When I started learning Haskell, one of the things that were put forward as major advantages, is how easy it is to model things with ADTs.

So I could very easily implement a binary tree just by writing

```hs
data BTree a = BLeaf | BNode a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

And so I found the idea of ADTs very fun, and began playing around with them in other languages, like Kotlin, where the above equivalent would be:

```kotlin
sealed class BTree<out T> {
    object BLeaf : BTree<Nothing>()
    data class BNode<T>(val value: T,
                        val left: BTree<T> = BLeaf,
                        val right: BTree<T> = BLeaf) : Tree<T>()
}
```

As I kept trying to apply ADTs to different problems of modeling state, I stumbled across this example:

We have the following game engine class

```kotlin
class GameEngine {
    fun gameState(): GameState { ... }
    fun process(action: Action): Result { ... }
}
```

Where the `gameState` lets you read the current state of the game, while `process` attempts to process some action according to the current game state, and return the appropriate response. Just imagine `Action` to be some type that appropriately encodes all possible actions that can be taken in the game by all players. The result of processing could be that the action failed (with a reason of failure) or succeeded (with the new game state), so `Result` is this

```
sealed class Result {
    data class ActionSucceeded(val gameState: GameState): Result()
    data class ActionFailed(var reason: FailReason): Result()
}
```

And the game state was either that it was ongoing or it was over (with the appropriate result)

```
enum class GameResult {
    DRAW, PLAYER_1_WON, PLAYER_2_WON
}

sealed class GameState {
    data object GameOngoing: GameState()
    data class GameEnded(var result: GameResult): GameState()
}
```

The reasons for `Result` to be `ActionFailed` would be that:

1. the game has ended, since no player action can be applied to a finished game
2. the player was acting out of turn
3. the player submitted an invalid move

So I modeled `FailReason` as follows

```kotlin
sealed class FailReason {
    data class GameEnded(var result: GameResult): FailReason()
    data object NotYourTurn: FailReason()
    data object InvalidMove: FailReason()
}
```

However, I noticed that `GameState.GameEnded` was IDENTICAL to `FailReason.GameEnded`, and so there was no reason to duplicate code and have it disconnected like that. Furthermore, if `FailReason.GameEnded` is updated to include more data about the end-state of the game, I want those same changes to automatically appear for the `FailReason` too. So instead of making `FailedReason` a `sealed class`, I made it a `sealed interface` to allow `GameState.GameEnded` to implement/inherit from it too, essentially multiple inheritance. `GameState.GameEnded` is a `GameState` but it is also a `FailReason`.

```kotlin
sealed class GameState {
    data object GameOngoing: GameState()
    data class GameEnded(var result: GameResult): GameState(), FailReason
}

sealed interface FailReason {
    data object NotYourTurn: FailReason
    data object InvalidMove: FailReason
}
```

And after I was done modelling this, I thought about how this would be done in Haskell? I am a beginner in Hasekll so trying things and failing is par for the course. I noticed that the thing analogous to the `sealed class` in Haskell, is the name of the `data type`:

```kotlin
sealed class Name { ... }    ~=    data Name = ...
```

And the thing that is analogous to the things that inherit this `sealed class` are the data constructors that you write with the ADT notation, but then if I try modeling my game engine example above I get something like

```hs
data Result = ActionSucceeded (GameState) | ActionFailed (FailReason)
data GameState = GameOngoing | GameEnded (GameResult)
data GameResult = Draw | Player1Won | Player2Won
data FailReason = GameEnded (GameResult) | NotYourTurn | InvalidMove
```

But now I don't know what to do, to make the `GameEnded` constructor create something that is both a `FailedReason` and `GameState`, as I did in Kotlin.

Or for example the exact same problem but in a different context. Lets say I have the following snippet of a Backus–Naur form specification for the syntax of a language:

```
<type>           ::= <base-type>
                   | <array-type>
                   | <pair-type>

<base-type>      ::= 'int'
                   | 'bool'
                   | 'char'
                   | 'string'

<array-type>     ::= <type> '[' ']'

<pair-type>      ::= 'pair' '(' <pair-elem-type> ',' <pair-elem-type> ')'

<pair-elem-type> ::= <base-type>
                   | <array-type>
                   | 'pair'
```

This VERY analogous to how Haskell `data` types would be defined, except for the fact that the names of the `data` types themselves, cannot be used as constructors in other `data` types.

I can model this in TypeScript directly, without any multiple inheritance even, like this

```js
type Type = BaseType | ArrayType | PairType
type BaseType = 'int' | 'bool' | 'char' | 'string'
type ArrayType = { type: Type }
type PairType = { first: PairElemType, second: PairElemType }
type PairElemType = BaseType | ArrayType | 'pair'

const typeConst: Type = { first: 'int', second: 'pair' }
```

I can also model this in Kotlin by first creating a diagram of "is-a" and "has-a" relationships (solid=is-a, dashed=has-a) [image]

And so, seeing multiple outgoing arrows for some of these, means they are multiple things simultaneously, and so I can again use interface multiple inheritance to make this

```kotlin
sealed interface Type {
    sealed interface BaseType: Type, PairElementType {
        data object Int: BaseType
        data object Bool: BaseType
        data object Char: BaseType
        data object Str: BaseType
    }
    class ArrayType(type: Type): Type, PairElementType
    class PairType(fst: PairElementType, snd: PairElementType): Type
}

sealed interface PairElementType {
    data object Pair: PairElementType
}
```

Where `ArrayType` and `BaseType` are both, `Type` *and* `PairElementType`, as per the specification above. Meaning I can make statements such as the following, no problem.

```kotlin
val type: Type = Type.PairType(Type.BaseType.Int, PairElementType.Pair)
```

I tried to come up with something similar in Haskell and the best I could do was to wrap the type I wanted with a constructor of a similar name

```hs
data Type = TBaseType BaseType | TArrayType ArrayType | TPairType PairType
data BaseType = Int | Bool | Char | Str
newtype ArrayType = ArrayType Type
data PairType = PairType PairElemType PairElemType
data PairElemType = PBaseType BaseType | PArrayType ArrayType | Pair
```

And so with that, it might not be possible to make a statement such as the following (which *feels* the equivalent of the Kotlin statement *if* Haskell had that multiple inheritance thing)

```hs
typeVal :: Type
typeVal = PairType Int Pair
```

However I can do it in a roundabout way like this:

```hs
typeVal :: Type
typeVal = TPairType $ PairType (PBaseType Int) Pair
```

So my question is, does Haskell have a feature where something can be of two different types (like with multiple interface inheritance), such that a constructor can produce something that is in fact compatible with two different types? Or is this impossible in Haskell, and with scenarios like that Game example, or the BNF spec, stuff would just have to be put in wrappers (as I have done)?

Comment: In what sense is the game ending a failure at all?

Comment: I wouldn't really call this particular case "code duplication". It is merely a coincidence that "game ended" is both a reason for failing to perform an action, and a game state. In other cases where there is more duplication, you can usually write a new `data` type for the shared constructors.

Comment: @chepner when someone tries to make a move for example.

Comment: Haskell types do not support inheritance, much less multiple inheritance. (Type classes have something that could be described as inheritance, but I wouldn't recommend using them here).

Comment: GameEnded is both a game state and a failure reason in the same sense that "empty list" is both a value that a list can take and a failure reason for e.g. a list indexing operation. We prefer to have these things as distinct values in distinct types though.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI If the game is over, the program should stop *accepting* moves.

Comment: @chepner implementing this such that a finished game rejects moves on the type level is not a beginner's task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a way to share a data constructor between multiple (families of) types. The closest you can get is to make a GADT that unifies the two types:

```
{-# Language DataKinds #-}
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data StateOrFail = State | Fail
data GameStateOrFailReason a where
    GameOngoing :: GameStateOrFailReason State
    GameEnded :: GameResult -> GameStateOrFailReason a
    NotYourTurn :: GameStateOrFailReason Fail
    InvalidMove :: GameStateOrFailReason Fail

type GameState = GameStateOrFailReason State
type FailReason = GameStateOrFailReason Fail
```

I would strongly recommend against this, though. It is conceptually messy -- it definitely doesn't map to the way *I* would think about these two types -- and it will be syntactically messy as well.

Comment: thankyou. I decided to try implementing the types in other languages too, and I got it to work in TypeScript (updated question), and then I stumbled across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67128531/haskell-type-synonym-union question that explained that what I did in typescript is called untagged unions - not supported by haskell. And then I found this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205585/is-there-a-compiler-extension-for-untagged-union-types-in-haskell where there are ways to simulate untagged unions, at the cost of exhaustiveness checking

Comment: @Daniel I think this answer would be better if you also explained what you recommend to do instead.

Comment: @4castle Simply duplicate the constructor, as is already done in the question proper. I think this is sort of implicit -- the question was roughly "I have X but I don't like it, can I do Y instead?", and the answer "You *can* do Y but shouldn't" to me strongly implies a "so stay with X".